# How to find the wave equation in a 1D box with a 2 different V(x) values

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

So this is for a simple infinite well $1$D box. The bounds are defined as

$V(x)=0$, for $0<x<\frac{L}{2}$, and $V(x)=V_0$ for $\frac{L}{2}<x<L$ with everywhere in the box having a potential $0$.

Now, my first wave equation from bound I think was

$\psi(x)=A\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{L})$

but now I'm lost on what to do when evaluating the wave function from $\frac{L}{2}<x<L$

I started by evaluating from $\psi(\frac{L}{2})=A\sin(kx)+B\cos(kx)=0$, but it doesn't feel as simple as when I had to evaluate the first bounds, since I don't know which or even if $A$ or $B$ will be eliminated.
I've now added a photo below to show what the box looked like to clear confusion.

I've been told my $V_0=6E_1^0$, where $E^0_1=\frac{h^2}{8mL^2}$

[image]

Also, here is my actual questions, since I'm probably phrasing them wrongly.

[image]

Comment: Your question is contradictory. Assuming that your "box" is the region $[0, L]$, in your first sentence you state that half of the box has $V = 0$ and the other half has $V = V_0$. In your second sentence you state that the potential is $0$ throughout. Also, if the potential in the box isn't a finite constant, then it's not an infinite square well, and you should not expect the solutions to be the same: for example, why should $\psi(L/2) = 0$? This was true of the original system because the wavefunction must be zero *outside of the box* where $V$ is infinite, but that's not applicable here.

Comment: Made sure to update and add a photo to maybe cover what i was to clear any miscommunication.

Comment: Okay, that helps. Well, then it's not right to say that "everywhere in the box [has] a potential 0", and also I probably wouldn't call this an infinite square well.

Comment: @orthocresol well then how would i go about finding the wavefunction at $V_0$? Would it include $A$ and $B$ from the base wave equation $A\cos(kx)+B\cos(kx)$, or does one of them get eliminated? I'm more confused at what happens at $\frac{L}{2}$

Comment: @2OpForTheSystem Understanding in the first place why $sin(x something)$ is the solution (your version is incorrect, missing $x$) would help you a lot. How familiar are you with the derivation of the "particle in the box"? It would be easier to start from there instead of fixating on an incorrect solution.

Comment: Quantum Theory (David Bohm) has a good discussion on square well potentials that you might find useful. This includes transmission coefficients, which you might need for the tunneling part.

Comment: You have two differential equations to solve throughout the whole region - one in the left half, one in the right half. They have different solutions with different arbitrary constants. What do you think should happen at the boundary between these two solutions (i.e. at L/2)? At that point both are valid, what does that imply? (Yes, I know ... but let's keep it simple)

Comment: @IanBush Does it imply that both $\psi(x)$ at $V(x)=0$ and $V_0$ are going to be identical solutions at the point $\frac{L}{2}$?

Comment: Can you give a good reason why they shouldn't? If they weren't equal what would that imply? Would that be physically reasonable? Maybe a read of something like http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m10/wave_functions.html might help